# Optimization - daily traffic patterns - is ABCA better than ACBA?

Tags: optimization, google-maps-api-3, routes

Is Google Maps API Route Optimization taking into account day of week and hour of day typical traffic patterns into consideration?

For instance, assume a route that starts at A, has to visit B and C, and then return to A.
On a typical Monday morning, ABCA proves shortest in time - that's how the traffic happens to work through these points.

On Mondays after 10PM, it proves best to use the route ACBA.

Can the Route Optimization suggest such kind of optimization?
More than just an optimal distance - time of travel taking traffic into account, including use of typical traffic patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Google use fastest time for distance calculation. Hence it should work like you want.

Comment: Thanks .. but the question is a bit twisted.  Need to know for a specific time in future - does Google use the fastest time for future distance calculation?  What is such time estimate based on?

Comment: Assuming that the optimization of point visit sequencing is resolved – 

Need  Directions from A to B to C and back to A, where we have to be 
at B in the time window Tb1..Tb2, at C in the time window Tc1..Tc2, by
car.

The route would suggest the time to depart and the route to follow.

Comment: Yes, but you can solve it with brute force. It it's then A-TB1 A-TB2?

Comment: @Phpdna can you point to the API reference where the described mechanism "here is a timeframe of arrival, please gimme start time" is described?

Comment: @ThomasS: There isn't such thing. You can look yourself through the google api.

Comment: @Phpdna Allright, that is also my state of knowledge. I was wondering because you answered "Yes, ..." to the question above. *confused*

Answer (score -1):

Currently there is nothing in the API what provides you with a suggestion to alternate destinations to have a lower travel time.

Comment: Assuming that the sequence optimization requirement is resolved, how about specifying desired timing to visit the points, e.g.: need to be at point B around time window tb1..tb2, need to be at C in time window tc1..tc2 - will the system suggest departure time, the route and the expected time to complete the route?

Comment: Downvoter care to elaborate? There is no API feature what will tell you the path with the total lowest travel time visiting A B C. Ofcourse you can calculate all permutations but once you have a few potentiall travel steps this will need a large amount of calculations.

Comment: @ThomasS: Of course there isn't a thing in the API. But you didn't mentionend that google already use fastet trip. Anything else is a speculation. I don't understand how you would calculate all permutations with this constraint? Can you show me an api that can solve this question (and also OP question)?

Comment: @Phpdna Google using the path with the lowest travel time is not the point. The OP asked if there is something provided that suggests "you want to visit A B C at Monday 9am, well then go from A to C then to B because thats faster at this time". This is not provided.

Comment: @ThomasS: It's all speculative what you wrote. That's why I downvoted you. Is there a Google Documentation how that calculate lowest travel time?

Comment: Example: calculate travel time A B C, A C B. Compare. Use lowest. Having the parameter durationInTraffic set DirectionsRequest will take current traffic into account. What do you miss in this solution?